# 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'profileChangeRequest'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

how's everyone? I hope you're safe and well!
I'm studying SWIFT and problem came across and honestly I don't have a clue i how to solve it. Can any one help me?
Here is the code bellow:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class CreateUserVC: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var userNameTxt: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var createBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelBtn: UIButton!
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        cancelBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    @IBAction func createUserTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        guard let email = emailTxt.text,
              let password = passwordTxt.text,
              let userName = userNameTxt.text else { return }
        
        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: "", password: "", completion: { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                debugPrint("Error creating user: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        
            let changeRequest = user.profileChangeRequest()
            changeRequest?.displayName = userName
            changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: {(error) in
        })
    })
}
    
    @IBAction func cancelTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4M6U.png)

Comment: “user" object which is of type “AuthDataResult?", has not such method profileChangeRequest() that you are trying to call. Check correctly if you are calling right method.

Comment: user is optional, because either you have a user or an error, user might be nil - you "if let unwrapped" the error, have to do the same for user

Answer (score 1):

The completion block of `Auth.auth.createUser` isn't invoked with a `User` object but with an optional `AuthDataResult` object.  So you need to check that the operation was successful by checking AuthDataResult isn't nil, retrieve the user object from it, then start your `profileChangeRequest`:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: "", password: "", completion: { (result, error) in
   guard let user = result?.user else {
      if let error = error {
         debugPrint("Error creating user: \(error.localizedDescription)")
      } else {
         debugPrint("Error creating user: unknown error")
      }
      return
   }

   let changeRequest = user.profileChangeRequest()
   changeRequest?.displayName = userName
   changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: {(error) in
   })
})
```